# Record the user who edited in a range columns

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA script records in the A column the user who modified the B column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 2017/10/12
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Target.Count = 1) Then
        If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing) Then _
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = Application.UserName
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("B:B"))
        If (Not xRg Is Nothing) Then
            For Each xCell In xRg
                xCell.Offset(0, -1) = Application.UserName
            Next
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I need a script to: write in the A column the name of pc user who edited in the columns range B:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the username to be written in column `A`, on the row any changes are made in column `B` to `S`right?
So something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Count = 1) And Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:S")) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Application.UserName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have one question. If column A is locked, when edit a cell in range defined B:S, I view an error VBA. Do you have any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: Either you unlock the cell with `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` before writing, or – if you want it to be locked and not having anything written there – just put that `On Error Resume Next` back in to hide the error.